# Mocking JDBC driver using Acolyte - transaction support?

Tags: scala, jdbc, mocking, scalatest

I'm using [Acolyte](http://acolyte.eu.org/) to mock a JDBC driver and test my DB layer in Scala.
It's alright but I can't find any way to test the transactional behavior (commit, rollback ...).

Basically I've got something which emulate a UnitOfWork and I'd like to test that if the commit and rollback command are appropriately invoked:

I've got something like this

```
def executeUnitOfWorkNoResult(sqlInstructions: List[String]) 
(connectionFactory:()=>Connection): Try[Unit] = {

import implicits.TryImplicits._

var connection: Connection = null

Try {
  connection = connectionFactory()
  connection.setAutoCommit(false)

  val execs = sqlInstructions.foldLeft(Try[Unit]())((tryInstance, sql)=> {
    tryInstance.flatMap(t => {

      val stmt:Statement = null
      Try {
        val stmt = connection.createStatement()
        stmt.execute(sql)
        ()
      }doFinally {

        Try{stmt.close}
      }
    })
  })

  execs match {
    case Success(_) => connection.commit()
    case Failure(e) => {
      connection.rollback()
      throw e
    }
  }

} doFinally {

  if (connection != null) {
    Try(connection.close)
  }
 }
```

}

Testing basic stuff is fine such as testing that commands are executed :

```
"executeUnitOfWork" should " execute commands" in {

 var insStmtCmt = 0;

 val handlerA = AcolyteDSL.handleStatement.withUpdateHandler { e =>

  if(e.sql.toLowerCase.startsWith("insert")){

    insStmtCmt = insStmtCmt+1
  }

  UpdateResult.One
}
def acquireMock() = AcolyteDSL.connection(handlerA)

val res = SqlUtils.executeUnitOfWorkNoResult(List(
  "insert into MetricDescription values('blaf','','','')",
  "insert into MetricDescription values('blaf2','','','')"))(acquireMock)

res.isSuccess shouldBe true

insStmtCmt should equal(2)
```

}

But anything related to transaction seems not supported.

In the doc it's written that there's a pseudo-support but I can't find it.

Any idea ?

Comment: Add code/example to make clear the goal.